# Is there a way to install Drupal from bash script without using Drush?

Tags: bash, drupal, command-line, drush

Looking for relatively easy way to install Drupal instance from command line without using Drush. 
I want just to use installing script and archive of custom modules to install Drupal on customer's server (it may not have Drush installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Drupal and additional modules and themes without Drush. It's just a sequence of UNIX commands, like `wget`, `tar xzf`, `cat`. You can even write a `Makefile` and use *GNU make* to deploy a website. But you don't want to do it (unless you have huge amounts of spare time at your diplosal). Drush provides a lot of best practices and convenience layers to bootstrap and deploy a Drupal installation.

The only reason not to use Drush is, when your server is only reachable via FTP. But then I would do `drush make` or all the `drush dl` on my local box and upload the resulting folder structure to the server.

Use Drush. ;)